# Comprobar si una variable existe en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, condiciones

tengo una duda un tanto tonta, pero tenía curiosidad por saber si esto es correcto. Si le paso a un if el nombre de una variable como el código de abajo, ¿es lo mismo que decir if (nombreVariable == true)?

let prueba = "Existe";

```
if (prueba) {
   console.log(prueba); 
}
```

Comment: Chequea esta pregunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113374/javascript-check-if-variable-exists-is-defined-initialized

Comment: No es exactamente lo mismo. Va a pasar la condicion siempre que no sea `false`, `0`, `null`.. No solo `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Respondiendo al titulo de la pregunta, tienes que verificar de que tipo es la variable, si es undefined entonces no existe.

```js
if(typeof nombre === 'undefined'){
     alert('no existe')
}
```

Respondiendo al body de tu pregunta, si la variable es de tipo booleano, ambas expresiones son equivalentes:

```js
let nombre = true

if(nombre){
  alert('la variable es true')
}
```

```js
let nombre = true

if(nombre === true){
  alert('la variable es true')
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Muy completa la respuesta.

Comment: De nada, estamos para ayudarnos :)

Comment: Si hacemos `const nombre = undefined` la variable existe, y tiene el valor `undefined`.

Comment: @Emeeus busque y busque pero no consegui una forma de resolver lo que propones, porque segun lo que entendi para javascript, una variable no definida y definida pero con el valor undefined son lo mismo, si tienes una solucion comenta y edito la repuesta para ayudar a otros https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined

Comment: Si, lo puse en una respuesta, en mi opinión la solución es  `try catch`, pero depende como interpretemos "si existe una variable".

Answer (score 6):

Ya tienes 2 excelentes respuestas, yo solo añadiré detalles o complementos a ambas.

En tu pregunta la duda es: *Comprobar si una variable existe en JavaScript*

Por ["existir"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existencia) podemos entender diferentes cosas, pero vamos a centrarnos en el lenguaje [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) y sus aspectos.

Javascript en su último estándar a fecha de hoy, define 9 tipos de datos:

1. Datos primitivos:

   - [Undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/undefined)
   - [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Boolean)
   - [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Number)
   - [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/String)
   - [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/BigInt)
   - [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Symbol)
2. [Null](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Null)
3. [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Object)
4. [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Function)

Como podemos observar `undefined` es un tipo de dato, por lo cual una variable puede ser de tipo `undefined`.

Si valoramos la "existencia" de algo como la definición dada en Wikipedia:

> ... atendiendo a su etimología, la palabra existencia significa «lo que está ahí» o «lo que está afuera».

entonces, podemos afirmar que **la existencia de una variable está relacionada con su "declaración", más que con su tipo**.

Y es que en Javascript, al ser un lenguaje de tipado dinámico, podemos declarar variables sin asignarles un valor o tipo. El lenguaje le asignará a estas variables (declaradas pero no inicializadas) el tipo `undefined`.

> ## undefined
>
> Un valor primitivo automáticamente asignado a las variables que solo han sido declaradas o a los argumentos formales para los cuales no existe argumentos reales.

Así, toda variable en Javascript "existe" siempre que tenga uno de los 9 tipos enumerados con anterioridad.

Ahora, ¿cómo podemos saber si una variable existe? (entiéndase *ha sido declarada*)

La aproximación de @Emeeus en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495158/comprobar-si-una-variable-existe-en-javascript/495169#495169) es muy buena. El intento de acceso a una variable no declarada, en un [ámbito (scope)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Scope) de ejecución, produce un [error de referencia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError):

> El objeto ReferenceError representa un error cuando se hace referencia a una variable inexistente.

Por lo que "inexistente" se refiere a variables que no han sido declaradas dentro de un ámbito de ejecución.

En la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/495158/comprobar-si-una-variable-existe-en-javascript/495160#495160) de @Ivandez, se usa el operador [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), para determinar la "existencia" de una variable, sin embargo **debemos tener cautela** al usar este método.

La razón por la cual digo que debemos tener cautela es porque este método no evalúa la variable, por lo cual un posible error de referencia puede ser pasado por alto:

> El operador typeof devuelve una cadena que indica el tipo del operando **sin evaluarlo**.

(negrillas agregadas por mi)

Podemos ver el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
let existe;

console.log(typeof existe);  // <- variable declarada
console.log(typeof exists);  // <- variable no declarada

if(!existe) console.log("no existe");
if(!exists) console.log("does not exists"); // Ooooopsss, ReferenceError
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se puede apreciar el operador `typeof` no es completamente fiable para realmente determinar la "existencia" de una variable.

Visto todo lo anterior, para determinar si una variable "existe" en Javascript, no sólo basta con conocer su tipo, sino que además debemos poder tener acceso a la misma.

No podemos escribir una función que haga el test, ya que todo argumento de una función es instanciado como una variable interna de la función, por lo tanto existe dentro de la misma. Es decir, si intento escribir una función que tome el nombre de una variable no declarada y pruebe si la misma existe o no, causará un error de referencia cuando sea llamada pasando como argumento la variable inexistente:

```js
// LO SIGUIENTE FUNCIONA
// capturo el error de referencia
try {
  let variable = existe;
  console.log(`Variable existe y su tipo es: ${typeof existe}`);
}
catch(e) {
  console.log(`Variable NO existe, el error es: ${e.message}.`);
}


// LO SIGUIENTE NO FUNCIONA

const existeVariable = function(variable) {
  // intento capturar un posible error de referencia
  try {
    let existe = variable;
    return true;
  }
  catch(e) {
    return false;
  }
}

console.log(existeVariable(existe)); // OOOPPPSSS
```

Espero que esto aclare aún más la duda y deje claro que si bien `typeof` es un operador muy potente, en algunas ocasiones no es del todo fiable.

Answer (score 3):

Si queremos saber si una variable ha sido declarada en cierto ámbito entiendo que no queda otra opción que usar `try catch`:

```js
const var1 = undefined;

if (typeof var1 === 'undefined') {

  console.log("var1 existe con el valor undefined");

}


if (typeof var2 === 'undefined') {

  console.log("var2 nunca fue definida, no existe");

}


try {
  var1;
} catch {
  console.log("NUNCA LLEGA AQUI PORQUE FUE DEFINIDA");
}

try {
  var2;
} catch {
  console.log("var2 nunca fue definida para este contexto");
}
```

La existencia o no es algo relativo, según mi visión, al hacer `const var1 = undefined` es claro que `var1` existe, con el valor primitivo `undefined`.

`var1`, paradójicamente definida como `undefined`, nunca va a lanzar una exepción por no estar definida, `var2`, realmente no definida, si va a lanzar exepciones.